# Laravel - Custome Auth Throttlelogins

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I have created a custom authentication and everything is working fine.
Now I am trying to add the Throttlelogins to prevent multiple incorrect login attempts. But The ThrottleLogins doesn't seem to load.

**Q: What am I missing here? or am I doing something wrong?**

The exception:

> Method
>   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\CustomersLoginController::hasTooManyLoginAttempts
>   does not exist.

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;

    use Auth;

    class CustomersLoginController extends Controller
    {    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest:customers');
        }

        public function ShowLoginForm()
        {
            return view('auth.customer-login');
        }

        public function login(Request $request)
        {
            $v = $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);

            if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
                $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

                return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
            }

            if(Auth::guard('customers')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember)){
                return redirect()->intended(route('customerdashboard'));
            };

            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }

        protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
        {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
            ]);
        }
        public function username()
        {
            return 'email';
        }


    }
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALPpL.png)
Can someone please explain what am I mssing?

Comment: I don't see how your login differs from Laravel's default login? Is there a specific reason you won't just modify / extends and overwrite the functions of Laravel?

Comment: I needed a sepeare login. The default one is used by admins and this one is used by customers. That's why I did two. This is the way I know how to do it. Is there a better way to do multiAuth without using any packages?

Comment: I have always used the same login for both myself, never found trouble with showing a specific URL to the admin panel, only when the currently loggedin user has the right permission. It may depends with the setup you have if admins and users are their own models or not aswell.

Comment: I have different models  and tables. So created separate guards and whole different auths.

Comment: That would make sense to have different authentication then, no real need to merge those together that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you are missing a function: hasTooManyLoginAttempts

In the function login you can see it's trying to call the function but it does not exist in your class. This is where it goes wrong.

**update**

In the AuthenticateUsers class, which you tried to copy, it's using ThrottlesLogins trait, which you are missing in your controller.

Update your controller like so:

```
class CustomersLoginController extends Controller
{    

    use ThrottlesLogins;
```

**Another update**

You tried to import the Trait which Laravel uses in their own Login. However this will not work here's why:

When you define a class, it can only have access to other classes within its namespaces. Your controller for instance is defined within the following namespace.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

So to use other classes, you need to import them from their own namespaces so you can access them. e.g.:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
```

Now that you have imported the ThrottlesLogins, which is actually a trait, now inside the class you use it to expose all of the methods inside.

Comment: I noticed that. That's why I had imported Throttlelogins. Do we have to again make a use ThrottlesLogins. Could you explain why? the logic.

Comment: use inside a class is to use traits. use outside is to import namespaces.

Comment: @Thomas Updated the answer to have a little more detail [More detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965155/laravel-custome-auth-throttlelogins/55965251#55965251)